# "Invert" a positive definite matrix in an inequality involving absolute value

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-definite

$\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert_\infty}$Suppose $A$ is a positive definite matrix, and $b$ is a strictly positive vector. (Actually, in our case, $b$ comprises square roots of the diagonal of $A$, i.e., $b_i=\sqrt{a_{ii}}$.)

We aim to describe solutions of the equation
$$ \operatorname{abs} Ax\leq b,\quad\text{i.e.,}\quad \Bigl\lvert \sum_j a_{ij} x_j\Bigr\rvert \leq b_i\; \forall i.$$

Obviously, this is equivalent to $-b\leq Ax\leq b$. However, I don't see a way how to apply $A^{-1}$ in such an inequality. Is there any way how to solve this equation?

Note that in the end, we will search for solutions lying on a certain lattice, so even ways that involve quite heavy computation are fine to us.

---

The best I've been able to obtain so far is the following necessary condition. We know that $\bigl\lvert \sum_j a_{ij} x_j\bigr\rvert \leq b_i\; \forall i$, hence also $\max_i \bigl\lvert \sum_j a_{ij} x_j\bigr\rvert \leq \max_i b_i$, i.e., $\norm{Ax}\leq\norm{b}$. From this we have that
$$ \norm{x} = \norm{A^{-1}Ax} \leq \norm{A^{-1}}\norm{Ax} \leq\norm{A^{-1}}\norm{b}. $$
This gives an upper bound on the coordinates of $x$, however, this works badly if the matrix $A$ is ill-conditioned.

Comment: What do $-b \le Ax$ and $Ax \le b$ mean?  i.e., what does it mean for one vector to be "less than" another?  That aside, what's wrong with just saying $-A^{-1}b \le x \le A^{-1}b$?

Comment: @tilper the inequalities have to hold in all coordinates of the vectors: $x\leq y\Leftrightarrow x_i\leq y_i \,\forall i$. As for the inversion, can you really do that with matrix inequalities? I mean, is positive definiteness of $A$ enough for this?

Comment: Ah nm, I see that now from your explanation of $\operatorname{abs} Ax \le b$.  I'm not entirely sure if positive-definiteness of $A$ is enough to guarantee that now that I think about it.

Comment: What sort of description of the solutions do you need?  Would an algorithm that could enumerate the possibly exponentially many solutions do?

Comment: @Qudit Well, yes, it would, or at least a good direction into how to attack the problem. I got _something_ this morning, but it's not really good, I'll update the question.

Comment: Your system has a parametric solution $Ax=r$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x=A^{-1}r$ for any parameter $r$ in the interval $-b\le r\le b$. Alternatively, you can try to use [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).